# How to center-align the right side of a multiline equation?

Tags: horizontal-alignment, align

\newbieallert

This is what I want to accomplish:

```
s = a + b + c
  +  de + fg
  +     h
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As suggested in the comments, you can use the `array` environment inside an equation.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\begin{array}{rc}
s =& a + b + c\\
  +&  de + fg\\
  +&     h
\end{array}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Comment: The right side of the equation will be left aligned, not centered `+ de + fg`

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see that in my browser. Check the update @ErikNeves

Comment: That update is perfect. Thank you!

Comment: @SebastiánV.Romero Can you explain what \newcolumntype{R}{>{$}r<{$}} and \newcolumntype{C}{>{$}c<{$}} do? I don't understand how they are able to enforce the constraints required by OP.

Comment: You can just use `\begin{equation}
\begin{array}{rcc}
s &=& a + b + c\\
  &+&  de + fg\\
  &+&     h
\end{array}
\end{equation}`. There is no need for a `tabular` and switching back and forth between math and text mode.

Comment: It forces to bring math mode to tabular columns, see what happen when you put `\begin{tabular}{RC}` and when you type `\begin{tabular}{rc}` @lazulikid

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Answer updated with two columns and not three. @Schrödinger'scat